How to print a datatable to pdf in flutter
I have a table of data retrieved from a Django rest api. Is there a way I can save the data table to pdf format?
If yes, I would like to know how I can print this table to pdf format.
The rows of the table are generated using snapshots from the api.
My code snippet for the data table is below:
                        DataTable(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        
                                      ),
                                      border: TableBorder.all(width: 0.2, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                                      columnSpacing: 80,
                                      dataRowHeight: 120,
                                      dividerThickness: 2,
                                      showCheckboxColumn: false,
                                      headingRowColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 228, 228)),
                                      columns: const <DataColumn>[
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('ID')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Visitor\'s Name')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Visit Date')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Time In')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Time Out')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Department')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Visitee')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Address')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
                                              DataColumn(label: Text('Purpose of Visit')),
                                      ], 
                                    rows: List.generate(
                                      snapshot.data!.length, 
                                      (index) {
                                        var data =  snapshot.data![index];
                                        
                                        return DataRow(
                                          
                                          cells: [
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.id.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.visitor_name.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.visit_date.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.Time_in.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                TextFormField(
                                                  initialValue: data.Time_out.toString()
                                                  
                                                  )
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.Department.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.Visitee_name.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.Address.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.Phone.toString())
                                              ),
                                              DataCell(
                                                Text(data.Purpose_of_visit.toString())
                                              ),
                                        ]
                                        );
                                      }
                                      
                                      ).toList(),
                                      
                                    ),

Any help would be appreciated.

You could try this package, https://pub.dev/packages/pdf
